# Font stretching in QML

Tags: qt, fonts, qml, qt5, stretch

We are converting some older QT widget code to use QML and I cannot find the equivalent property for the [`QFont::setStretch()`](https://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/qfont.html#setStretch) operation.

The [QML Font page](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-font.html) shows only family, bold, italic, underline, pointSize, pixelSize, weight, overline, strikeout, capitalization, letterSpacing, wordSpacing, kerning, preferShaping and hintingPreference.

This font selection is being done within a `Text` object, along the lines of:

```
Text {
    font.family: "LiberationSans"
    font.pixelSize: 178
    font.weight: 80
    //font.stretch: 75 - doesn't work, no such property
}
```

Is there no way to set the stretch factor in QML. We're using Qt 5.6 by the way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately this property is not exposed to QML, a possible solution is to use a helper class that receives the QFont, change the stretch and return the new QFont.

**main.cpp**

```
#include <QGuiApplication>
#include <QQmlApplicationEngine>
#include <QQmlContext>
#include <QFont>

class FontHelper: public QObject{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    using QObject::QObject;
    Q_INVOKABLE QFont changeStretchFont(const QFont & font, int factor){
        QFont fn(font);
        fn.setStretch(factor);
        return fn;
    }
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication::setAttribute(Qt::AA_EnableHighDpiScaling);

    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);

    QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
    FontHelper helper;
    engine.rootContext()->setContextProperty("fontHelper", &helper);
    engine.load(QUrl(QStringLiteral("qrc:/main.qml")));
    if (engine.rootObjects().isEmpty())
        return -1;

    return app.exec();
}

#include "main.moc"
```

**main.qml**

```
import QtQuick 2.9
import QtQuick.Window 2.2

Window {
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480
    title: qsTr("Hello World")

    Text {
        id: txt
        font.family: "Helvetica"
        font.pointSize: 13
        font.bold: true
        text: "hello World"
        Component.onCompleted: txt.font = fontHelper.changeStretchFont(txt.font, 200)
    }
}
```

Comment: Hmm, something weird happens when I use this method. It appears that the characters stay the same width but they're heavily compressed. For example, the word PAX would only be a little wider than P but with the A starting about a quarter in to the P.

Comment: @paxdiablo In Qt 5.12.2 I do not observe this problem as it shows the following images: https://imgur.com/a/xa56SVc , maybe it is a bug of the version of Qt that you us

Comment: I don't think it's a bug of the version, that same version is being used for the Widget variant where the font width is scaled okay. However, I'm don't have a simple situation like the one you gave as an example, we actually construct all the QML elements then we change the font details later. Hence there is a function provided in the Text control to change the font details. It may be that I'm doing something wrong there, I'll need to investigate.

Comment: @paxdiablo mmm, it seems strange, you could show me a picture of the error, and if you provide an MCVE maybe it can help you analyze the problem

Comment: I'll work on getting a shortest version possible done in the next day or so, we're somewhat under the pump now so have decided to use the full width fonts as they are. Since your answer *did* actually affect the width (and is a neat trick to have learnt about), I'll accept this as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Text {
    font.family: "LiberationSans"
    font.pixelSize: 178
    font.weight: 80
    transform: Scale { xScale: 0.75}
    //font.stretch: 75 - doesn't work, no such property
}
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.