# QML/Qt: Make displayed text as large as possible depending on the parent containing it

Tags: qt, widget, qml, kde-plasma

I am trying to make a very simple KDE-Plasma Widget where only a certain number is displayed. I want to make this displayed number have a font size as large as possible depending on the parent containing it.
Here is what it looks right now:

[image]

As you can see, the text inside has a lot of space around it. What I actually want it to be is something like the "Date And Time" Widget found in KDE Plasma (my widget is right next to it for comparison):

[image]

Here, the time displayed has much lesser space around it while also auto-resizing whenever the panel height is changed.

Here is what the current code looks like:

```
import QtQuick 2.6
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.0
import org.kde.plasma.components 2.0 as PlasmaComponents
import org.kde.plasma.plasmoid 2.0


Item {
    id: main
    anchors.fill: parent
    Layout.minimumWidth: units.iconSizes.large
    Layout.minimumHeight: units.iconSizes.large

    
    Plasmoid.preferredRepresentation: Plasmoid.fullRepresentation


    PlasmaComponents.Label {
        id: display

        anchors {
            fill: parent
            margins: Math.round(parent.width * 0.1)
        }

        verticalAlignment: Text.AlignVCenter
        horizontalAlignment: Text.AlignHCenter

        text: foobar

        font.pixelSize: 1000;
        minimumPointSize: theme.smallestFont.pointSize
        fontSizeMode: Text.Fit
        font.bold: true
    }

    Timer {
        some stuff
    }
}
```

I tried looking into the code of the above Date and Time widget and wrote down the exact same layouts/controls (which is what you are seeing in the above code) with the same positioning/styling properties and yet I get a lot of space around my text/or the font size continues to remain small.

Comment: You have conflicting sizes. You're setting `anchors` to fill the parent minus a margin value, but you're also setting `width` and `height` to match the parent's full size. You should use only one of those, not both. I doubt that will fix your problem, but it will at least avoid confusion.

Comment: @JarMan I have edited my question. Thanks for that. But yeah, it hasn't solved my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @JarMan's input I was able to realize that my text was being rendered in small font because of lack of space due to the root (`item`) element being square in shape.

I have now figured that to change the layout sizes of the root element inside the KDE-Plasma panel, one needs to mess with `Layout.preferredWidth` and `Layout.preferredHeight`.

Here is what I did:

```
item {
    .
    .
    Layout.preferredWidth: 150 * units.devicePixelRatio
    Layout.preferredHeight: 50 * units.devicePixelRatio
    .
    .
}
```

Note: the 150 and 50 values aren't final. It basically gives an idea about the ratio at which the root element's width and height should be in (and I wanted a rectangle). It automatically resizes the inner content too as the Plasma Panel is resized.

Answer (score 1):

I tried your code and it resized the font correctly. For the spacing around the text, there are two points:

1. The spacing on the left and right is easily controlled by adjusting the `margins` value that you are using. For less space, try `Math.round(parent.width * 0.05)`.

[image]

2. The spacing on the top and bottom is larger because the shape of your parent object is square, while the shape of the text is rectangular. In order to make the text fit the height of the square without exceeding the width of the square, the text would not just need to resize, it would need to be stretched vertically. But QML does not have an easy way to do that, and I doubt that's really what you want anyway.

[image]

**EDIT:**

And if you do want font stretching, I'll point you to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55348881/7427152) answer.

Comment: Thanks for explaining! I set the height and width of `item` manually to make it rectangular (height: 50; width: 100) and so it's a lot more proper now looking at the widget when it is by itself or placed in the desktop. Now the only problem is that, when I am adding this widget to the KDE Panel, the item's height and width are ignored and they are set to 100 each. This again makes my text look really small in the panel alone.

Comment: I don't know anything about KDE components. Maybe try setting an `implicitWidth` and `implicitHeight` on the root Item of your widget?

Comment: I just tried it, that didn't work either sadly. I find it strange that it's not resizable. I looked at the code of the "Date and Time" widget and nowhere can I find any relevant code that sets the root item as a rectangle thus allowing the text inside to fit in neatly.